# Unable to delete Mailbox on iPhone 4S

Tags: email, iphone

I have an iPhone 4S. Software 5.0.1

I have configured the Mail to GMail. Now, I want to delete the mailbox. Here is what I do.

1. Click on the Mail icon
2. Click on Edit
3. Click on [Gmail]
4. Click on Big Red button called Delete Mailbox
5. Click on Delete Mailbox prompt
6. I get an error message as below - 
   Unable to Delete Mailbox. The mailbox could not be deleted on the server.

I have tried it multiple times but to no avail.

Any suggestions / thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete the inbox in your settings...

Settings < Mail, Contacts, Calendars

Select your account and hit the delete button. It will completely delete the account from your iPhone, not the GMail servers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`[Gmail]` and its children (`Important`, `Spam`, `Starred`) are not regular mailboxes (or tags, as internally used by Gmail), they are linked to specific Gmail functionality and therefore cannot be deleted. You can delete tags/mailboxes that you defined.

Comment: Vlad: Thanks! So, how do I not allow it to sync and remove the emails as such from Mail i.e., I do not want anyone (folks at home) to click on the Mail and read my email.

Comment: Ignore me. Removed it from Settings.